# Constant value od 375 when printing view's bounds.width property across different simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I'm experiencing a very weird thing inside my application. I have a view whose constraints are set in order to stick its edges to both the phone's edges. The thing works perfectly and the view fills all the screen, but when I try to print the `self.bounds.width` property it always returns me `375.0` despite I've tried that with multiple devices simulators. Can anyone explain me that?

Comment: Are you doing this in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @AshleyMills yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `layoutIfNeeded()` method before trying to use any of the view's attributes. This method will force the view to update its layout.

e.g.:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    print(view.width) // now you will get the right size
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much...that's way better than call the method inside viewWillAppear

Comment: Yep. That's the right approach to do it. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 2):

The width you're seeing is the width of the view in your storyboard. If you set the device to be a iPhone SE size in the storyboard, you'll get a width of 320.

Once the view has been resized for the actual device it's running on you'll get the correct value.

Try in one of

```
viewDidAppear
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

Comment: I tried it...Inside viewDidAppear works perfectly...thank u very much!